# How to fit linear models to several randomly generated datasets using the tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I'm currently reading through Hadley Wickham's R for Data Science and came across the exercices in 23.2.1, dealing with the robustness of linear models that were fitted with squared differences to randomly generated datasets.

I tried to implement this using tidyverse packages.

```
generate_data <- function(seed){
  set.seed(seed)
  tibble(
    x = rep(1:10, each = 3),
    y = x * 1.5 + 6 + rt(length(x), df = 2),
    seed = as.character(seed)
  )
}
seeds <- 6:11
datasets <- seeds %>% 
  map(generate_data)
```

This is the crucial point. The datasets exist in a list of dataframes, so I used the `map` function, finally extracting the coefficients of the respective model with `coef`. In this process however I lose the information on the seed that was used and hence the link to the dataset it refers to, which forces me to do the ugly `mutate(seed = as.character(seeds))` thing.

```
model_parameters <- datasets %>%
  map(~ lm(y ~ x, data = .)) %>%
  map(coef)

model_parameters <- model_parameters %>% 
  map_df(bind_rows) %>% 
  mutate(seed = as.character(seeds))
```

Convert the list of dataframes into a single one for plotting:

```
datasets <- datasets %>% map_df(bind_rows)

ggplot(datasets,
       aes(x,y, col = seed)
       ) +
  geom_jitter(width = .1) +
  geom_abline(
    data = model_parameters,
    aes(
      intercept = `(Intercept)`, 
      slope = x,
      color = seed
    )
  )
```

My solution seems somewhat ugly. Is there a more natural approach to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've added the seed column its usually easier to work with one large data.frame than a list of data.frames. So you could do

```
library(tidyverse)
datasets <- seeds %>% 
  map_df(generate_data)
```

and then when extracting coefficients, the `broom` package can help in a tidy way. For example

```
model_parameters <- datasets %>% group_by(seed) %>% 
  do(broom::tidy(lm(y~x, .))) %>% 
  select(seed, term, estimate) %>% 
  spread(term, estimate)
```

Then these can both go directly into the `ggplot` code you've already written

Comment: Great, thanks alot! I wasn't aware of the `do` function